# Rails Model label field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with RoR. I need to define which database field must be used as a label, just as it does CakePhp. Maybe is a basic question but I'm against the time. Thanks.

[image: DisplayField in Cake]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to override `to_s`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    username
  end
end

# usage
user = User.new(username: "jackofalltrades")
puts user # => "jackofalltrades"
```

If you use this technique, be sure that the attribute (`username` in this case) is present.